# Pandas Dataframe Boxplot Y axis not correct scale

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I am trying to use the `boxplot`  feature of Pandas Dataframe but some of my features have different scale than others, which makes the charts look bad, it is impossible to read the Y values of the smallest ones.

Here is my code:

```
df.boxplot(by='label', figsize=(30,30))
```

And I get a grid of 4 by 4 charts, with 4 labels for each which is correct.

However, the scale is adjusted for the largest values not individually per charts.

Is there a way to solve this ? Thanks !

**Update:**

Here is something I tried:

```
charts = df.boxplot(by='label', figsize=(30,30), return_type='axes')

for ax in charts:
   y_axe_name = ax.get_title()
   min_value = all_data[y_axe_name].min()
   max_value = all_data[y_axe_name].max()
   ax.set_ylim(0, max_value + (20 * max_value / 100))

plt.show()
```

I was inspired by [Set y-axis scale for pandas Dataframe Boxplot(), 3 Deviations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892300/set-y-axis-scale-for-pandas-dataframe-boxplot-3-deviations) but it still not working. The charts are still sharing the same y axes.

Answer (score 0):

The best walkaround I found is to normalize the dataset:

```
def normalized(df, column_name):
  df[column_name].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
  df[column_name] = df[column_name] / df[column_name].max()
  return df
```

That way the y-scale is between 0 and 1.