# Change y-axis range in Pandas.boxplot()

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I use the following `boxplot` function from [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html),

```
df.boxplot(column=['D1', 'D2'])
```

and I would like to change the y-axis range. However, I didn't see such an option in the document. Any idea for that?

Comment: Hope so you find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892300/set-y-axis-scale-for-pandas-dataframe-boxplot-3-deviations

Comment: Or may be here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-the-range-of-y-axis-for-a-seaborn-boxplot-using-matplotlib#:~:text=Using%20boxplot()%2C%20draw%20a,use%20the%20show()%20method.

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/40895458/859227 but I get `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'values'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so editing the axis-object - you can either do

```
ax = df.boxplot(column=['D1', 'D2'])
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
```

or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fix, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
df.boxplot(column=['D1', 'D2'], ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
```

figure is the whole graphic, ax is the diagram. `plt.subplots(1, 1)` is the number of diagrams(rows, columns), in this case 1 - so ax is just one diagram. Otherwise ax would be a list of axis objects.